# Getting column names as values while unpivoting in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot

I have some sample data as follows;

```
col_1 | col_2 | val_1 | val_2
 ----------------------------
  TPEB| SMB   | 12.0  | 12.7
  FEWB | ENT  | 13    | 10
```

The goal is to get output as follows;

**Expected Output**

```
dimension   | dimension_value | val_1 | val_2

 [col_1,col_2] | [TPEB,SMB]   | 12.0   | 12.7
 [col_1,col_2] | [FEWB,ENT]   |  13    | 10
```

As we can see, we need to get column names as values as well as concatenated here.

In my knowledge some sort of unpivoting may help. Here is my attempt.

```
select *
from table
unpivot (slice_value for slice_name in (col_1, col_2));
```

This will give following output as expected;

```
slice_name | slice_value | val_1 | val_2
  col_1    |  TPEB        | 12.0 | 12.7
  col_2    |  SMB         | 12.0 | 12.7
  col_1    |  FEWB        | 13   | 10
  col_2    |   ENT        | 13   | 10
```

Can I please get some help on how to implement the concatenation as we're looking for in snowflake dialect?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am going to guess, you want this to work for "any table" aka not hard code the column names? Which means this needs to be dynamic SQL, Snowflake Scripting

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim appreciate your feedback. Actually the column names can be hard coded here. it may not be needed to use dynamic sql.  If possible we can stay with static sql.

Answer (score 1):

### Fixed Answer:

So the example you show is not, unpivot, as the 2 value column width is still preserved.

it's just this SQL:

```
select
    '[col_1,col_2]' as dimension,
    '['||col_1||','||col_2||']' as dimension_value ,
    val_1, val_2
from data as d
order by 1;
```

thus with data:

```
with data(col_1, col_2, val_1, val_2) as (
    select * from values
      ('TPEB', 'SMB', 12.0, 12.7),
      ('FEWB', 'ENT', 13  , 10)
)
```

gives:

| DIMENSION | DIMENSION_VALUE | VAL_1 | VAL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [col_1,col_2] | [TPEB,SMB] | 12 | 12.7 |
| [col_1,col_2] | [FEWB,ENT] | 13 | 10 |

Or using ARRAY_CONSTRUCT:

```
select
    array_construct('col_1','col_2') as dimension,
    array_construct(col_1,col_2) as dimension_value ,
    val_1, val_2
from data as d
order by 1;
```

gives:

| DIMENSION | DIMENSION_VALUE | VAL_1 | VAL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ "col_1", "col_2" ] | [ "TPEB", "SMB" ] | 12 | 12.7 |
| [ "col_1", "col_2" ] | [ "FEWB", "ENT" ] | 13 | 10 |

And if you want to use UNPIVOT as your base, [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html):

```
with data(col_1, col_2, val_1, val_2) as (
    select * from values
      ('TPEB', 'SMB', 12.0, 12.7),
      ('FEWB', 'ENT', 13  , 10)
)
select 
    array_agg(slice_name) as dimension
    ,array_agg(slice_value) as dimension_value
    ,val_1
    ,val_2
from data
unpivot (slice_value for slice_name in (col_1, col_2))
group by 3,4
order by 1;
```

gives:

| DIMENSION | DIMENSION_VALUE | VAL_1 | VAL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ "COL_1", "COL_2" ] | [ "TPEB", "SMB" ] | 12 | 12.7 |
| [ "COL_1", "COL_2" ] | [ "FEWB", "ENT" ] | 13 | 10 |

and if you want those arrays as strings [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string.html):

```
select 
    array_to_string(array_agg(slice_name), ',') as dimension
    ,array_to_string(array_agg(slice_value), ',') as dimension_value
    ,val_1
    ,val_2
from data
unpivot (slice_value for slice_name in (col_1, col_2))
group by 3,4
order by 1;
```

| DIMENSION | DIMENSION_VALUE | VAL_1 VAL_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| COL_1,COL_2 | TPEB,SMB | 12 |
| COL_1,COL_2 | FEWB,ENT | 13 |

Or you can directly transform in string space with [LISTAGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html)

```
select 
    LISTAGG(slice_name, ',') as dimension
    ,LISTAGG(slice_value, ',') as dimension_value
    ,val_1
    ,val_2
from data
unpivot (slice_value for slice_name in (col_1, col_2))
group by 3,4
order by 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to hardcode column names, isn't it easier done with `union all`?

```
select 'col_1' as slice_name, col_1 as slice_value, val_1, val_2
from t
union all
select 'col_2', col_2, val_1, val_2
from t
```

Comment: That is how to hand roll the "unpivot" but what they asked for as the output, is not an unpivot.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Yeah, the output is a basic data reshaping presented as an "unpivot" problem, which it's not.